# How to avoid allocating memory by using reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    A(std::string s) { name = s; }

    std::string name;
};

struct B {
    B(std::string s) : a(A(s)) {}

    A& a;
};

int main() {
    B b("tom");

    std::cout << b.a.name << std::endl;
}
```

I am trying to assign `class B`'s A& a with `A's object`. Couple of ways I could do that.

1)  make A& a to A* a and do a = new A(s) inside B's constructor. This works but I am trying to avoid this since I have to do new and delete.

2) Above I have `class B` which takes string and creates a rvalue object to initialize lvalue reference. This will give compilation error.

3) I can make `A& a` to `A&& a`, but not sure if this is good. Since it compiles but cout gives garbage.

4) Create instance of A in main and pass it to B's constructor. But am trying to avoid this for now.

Comment: _"I am trying to assign `class B`'s A& a with `A's object`"_ What does that mean?

Comment: Your code is not well-formed. You cannot initialize `B::a` from `A(s)`. The former is an lvalue reference, the latter is an rvalue.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, the question admits that (point #2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need references, or pointers, or anything like that.

You just need an object of type `A`, simple as that.

Plus you can avoid all copies by using move semantics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A(std::string s) : name(std::move(s)) {}

    std::string name;
};

struct B
{
   B(std::string s) : a(std::move(s)) {}

   A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b("tom");

    std::cout << b.a.name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @vantamula: Is it the string copies you were worried about? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: I did not wanted to create instance of A in main and pass it to B. I just wanted to place A inside B.

Comment: I could have use `A()=default` and tried to create instance of A inside constructor of B. But was not sure that effort was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Correct and good code would look like this:

```
struct A
{
    A(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}

    std::string name_;
};

struct B
{
    B(std::string name) : a_(std::move(name)) {}

    A a_;
};
```